# Нехватка переводов в новом выпадающем блоке для строки поиска

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, поиск

В выпадающем блоке у строки поиска из главной шапки не достаёт некоторых переводов:

> [image: выпадающий поиск]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переводы добавлены:

> [image: перевод выпадающей подсказки]